# Excel VBA loop macro for each selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that simply changes the value of a cell in a selected row.

```
Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 20).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "withdraw"
```

However I would like to be able to select a number of rows, not necessarily consecutive, for example select A1, A3 and A4 from the following example, and have the macro change column B for each select cell so,

```
    A        B  
1 Brian
2 James
3 Jenny
4 Frank
5 Tim
```

Becomes

```
    A        B  
1 Brian   Withdraw
2 James
3 Jenny   Withdraw
4 Frank   Withdraw
5 Tim
```

How would I go about getting the active row from the a selected range and loop the macro for each row?

Comment: Can the desired cells be algorithmically determined (follow a certain pattern), or are they random?

Comment: How do you want to identify the cells that want the action to be carried out on?

Comment: They will be random, selected by holding ctrl. The idea is to be able to select a list of names and set each selected name to 'withdraw', purely to speed up doing it on a row by row basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution for you:

```
Private Sub a()
    Dim sSel As String
    Dim aSel As Variant
    Dim rX As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    sSel = Selection.Address
    aSel = Split(sSel, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(aSel)
        Set rX = Application.ActiveCell.Parent.Range(CStr(aSel(i)))
        For j = 1 To rX.Rows.Count
            rX.Rows(j).EntireRow.Cells(1, 2) = "withdraw"
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Please not that this allows you to select anywhere and any number of cells per any row.

Comment: Thank you for this, however is it only compatible in a certain version of Excel or VBA as 'Set rX = Me.Range' is throwing up an error "Invalid use of Me keyword"?

Comment: @TimWilkinson Sorry, my mistake... thought you knew VBA a bit better... Please see the edit above.

Comment: My apologies, still on the learning path, hence the simplicity of my OP! Thank you very much for your help, exactly what I was after.

Comment: @TimWilkinson np at all, but you **must** read up on "Me" keyword. It has nothing to do with versions whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code should work for you:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Selection
    r.Offset(, 1) = "Withdraw"
End Sub
```